# How do I make a jsoncpp array?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, jsoncpp

I'm stuck with [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). I would like to create an array like this:

```
"Cords": [{"x": 10, "y": 20}, {"x": 70, "y": 40}, {"x": 15, "y": 65}]
```

I managed to do the regular stuff with jsoncpp (see below) but I am stuck in this case of making a JSON array.

```
Json::Value event;

event["name"] = "Joe";
event["Direction"]["left"]["x"] = "1338";
event["Direction"]["right"]["x"] = "1337";
```

**Edit:**
I want to print it all within event.
I do not want to print cords separately.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your code does not correspond to expected JSON in any way.

Comment: btw http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#ada6ba1369448fb0240bccc36efaa46f7 and http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#ac9182982c361e0ab621134d406e5f250

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `int` overload of `operator[]` to define an array

```
Json::Value coord(int x, int y)
{
    Json::Value result;
    result["x"] = x;
    result["y"] = y;
    return result;    
}

void make_event(Json::Value & event)
{
    Json::Value & coords = event["Cords"];
    coords[0] = coord(10, 20);
    coords[1] = coord(70, 40);
    coords[2] = coord(15, 65);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, @Caleth what would be the best practice if I would have to put this into a function that is void? Right now it says a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: move the definition of `coord` outside the function that is using it

Comment: Works just like intended! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

```
Json::Value min;
Json::Value event;
event["x"] = 10;
event["y"] = 20;
min["Cords"] = event;



// Output to see the result

cout<<min.toStyledString()
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it within Json::Value event; somehow? I do not want to print it alone as I am already including other data to event and printing it as a whole.